# How to calculate input value with tap on keyboard

Tags: jquery, input

I have 5 input tags:

```js
$(".value").keydown(function(event) {
  var ok = 48;
  var it = 57;
  if (event.which >= ok && event.which <= it || event.which == 8) {
  } else if (event.which == 9) {
    var num1 = parseInt($("#num1").val());
    var num2 = parseInt($("#num2").val());
    var num3 = parseInt($("#num3").val());
    var num4 = parseInt($("#num4").val());
    if (num1 && num2) {
      $("#num3").html(num1 + num2);
    } else if (num3 && num4) {
      $("#num5").val(num3 + num4); //on this line it's not showing the value, i dont know what it's going on
    }
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="num1" class="value">
<input type="text" id="num2" class="value">
<input type="text" id="num3" class="value">
<input type="text" id="num4" class="value">
<input type="text" id="num5" class="value">
```

If I input value on `#num1` and `#num2`, then I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> on keyboard, the result is showing on `#num3`; it's done.

However, if I input on #num4, then I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> on keyboard, it's not showing on `#num5`.

Comment: better you use type=number and set min max value

Comment: @plonknimbuzz it's doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me: leave the first 2 fields empty, type 15 in field 3, type 25 in field 4 and press tab and field 5 is populated with the value 40. What are you expecting and how do you think it is failing? BTW, I don't think calling html() on field 3 is what you want - it doesn't work with an input that is not valid HTML. Perhaps you meant val() there too.

Comment: it's my fault,i meant val(), not html(), i want input first tag  until end tag, not from num3 , num4, num1 then num2.
can you help me @andrew

Comment: @DioSatriaDarma - sorry but I don't understand what you want. Can you please update the question and describe the steps the user would take and the behaviour you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
$(".value").keydown(function(event) {

var $val = jQuery(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
                if (isNaN($val)) {
                    $val = 0;
                }
 jQuery(this).val($val);// replace to allow number only 
  var ok = 48;
  var it = 57;

  if (event.which >= ok && event.which <= it || event.which == 8) {
  } else if (event.which == 9) {
    var num1 = parseInt($("#num1").val());
    var num2 = parseInt($("#num2").val());
    var num3 = parseInt($("#num3").val());
    var num4 = parseInt($("#num4").val());
    if (num1 && num2) {
      $("#num3").val(num1 + num2);
    }
    if (num3 && num4) {
      $("#num5").val(num3 + num4); //on this line it's not showing the value, i dont know what it's going on
    }
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOVZ9DFZ00LO

Answer (score 0):

use `type=number` much be easier

```js
$(function(){
 function parser(d){
  return isNaN(parseInt(d)) ? 0 : parseInt(d);
 }
 
 $('#num1, #num2').change(function(){
  $('#num3').val(parser($('#num1').val()) + parser($('#num2').val())).change();
 });
 $('#num3, #num4').change(function(){
  $('#num5').val(parser($('#num3').val()) + parser($('#num4').val()));
 });
 
  //second code
  
  $('#num11, #num22').change(function(){
  $('#num33').val(parser($('#num11').val()) + parser($('#num22').val())).change();
 });
 $('#num33, #num44').change(function(){
  $('#num55').val(parseInt($('#num33').val()) + parseInt($('#num44').val())).change();
 });
  
  $('#num33').change(function(){
    if(parser($('#num33').val()) == parser($('#num11').val()) + parser($('#num22').val())){
      $('#num33').removeClass('red');
    } else{
      $('#num33').addClass('red');
    }
  });
 
  
  $('#num55').change(function(){
    if(parser($('#num55').val()) == parser($('#num33').val()) + parser($('#num44').val())){
      $('#num55').removeClass('red');
    } else{
      $('#num55').addClass('red');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.red{border: 2px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="num1" class="value">
<input type="number" min="0" id="num2" class="value">
<input type="number" min="0" readonly id="num3" class="value">
<input type="number" id="num4" class="value">
<input type="number" readonly id="num5" class="value">

<hr>
if you dont want set readonly, probably you will do like below:<br>

<input type="number" id="num11" class="value">
<input type="number" id="num22" class="value">
<input type="number" id="num33" class="value">
<input type="number" id="num44" class="value">
<input type="number" id="num55" class="value">
```